# Moving circle using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made a circle and then another one inside. I have to move the little circle around inside the big one.

I have all the values of theta inside a np.array. I want the circle moving around for each value of rtheta. I don't know how to "animate" the circle.

```
def hypotrochoide(R, r):
   
   theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
   
   R= R/2
   
   
   x = R*np.cos(theta)
   y = R*np.sin(theta)
   
   
   r= r/2
   
   rTheta= np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
   
   iCircleX = ((R- r) * np.cos(0)) + r*np.cos(theta)
   iCircleY = ((R- r) * np.sin(0)) + r*np.sin(theta)

   
   

   plt.axis('equal')
   
   
   plt.plot(x,y)
   plt.plot(iCircleX,iCircleY)
   


    
hypotrochoide(10, 4)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is my solution using Pandas and Plotly Express, which has an animation feature:**

Here are the packages you need:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import plotly.tools as tls
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot, download_plotlyjs
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

First I wrote two helper functions: one that calculated all the points of a circle with radius r and center (centerX,centerY), and another that find all the points of the outer AND inner circle.

```py
# Create functions
def circle_pts(centerX, centerY, r):
    allTheta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    x = r*np.cos(allTheta) + centerX
    y = r*np.sin(allTheta) + centerY
    
    return x, y

def hypotrochoide_calculations(R, r, theta):
    # Find points of outer circle
    outerX, outerY = circle_pts(0, 0, R)
    
    # Find points of inner circle
    centerInnerX = (R - r)*np.cos(theta)
    centerInnerY = (R - r)*np.sin(theta)
    innerX, innerY = circle_pts(centerInnerX, centerInnerY, r)
    
    return outerX, outerY, innerX, innerY
```

Then I calculate all the point data (outer and inner x and y) for all the thetas between 0 and 2pi rad and load it into a Pandas DataFrame.

```py
# Get data
stepSize = 100
R = 5
r = 1

data = np.zeros((stepSize*stepSize, 5))          # Create empty array

# Create full stepSize^2 list of thetas (each one repeated 100 times)
allTheta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, stepSize)
fullThetas = []
for i in range (allTheta.shape[0]):
    for j in range(stepSize):
        fullThetas.append(allTheta[i])
data[:,0] = fullThetas

# For 0 to 2pi thetas 
for i in range(allTheta.shape[0]):
    # Calculate outer and inner circle points
    outerX, outerY, innerX, innerY = hypotrochoide_calculations(R, r, allTheta[i])
    
    # Calculate row indices
    idxStart = 100*i
    idxEnd = idxStart + 100
    
    # Set outer/inner x/y coordinates to the proper rows in the array
    data[idxStart:idxEnd, 1] = outerX
    data[idxStart:idxEnd, 2] = outerY
    data[idxStart:idxEnd, 3] = innerX
    data[idxStart:idxEnd, 4] = innerY
    
# Create Pandas DataFrame out of array
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['Theta', 'Outer_X','Outer_Y','Inner_X','Inner_Y']
df
```

Then I give that DataFrame to the Plotly Expression function and specify it to animation across all the theta

```py
# Create plotly animation
fig = px.scatter(df, x='Inner_X', y='Inner_Y', animation_frame='Theta')
fig.add_trace(px.scatter(df, x='Outer_X', y='Outer_Y').data[0])

fig.update_layout(title='Hypotrochoide Animation', height=600, width=600)
fig.update_xaxes(range=[-6,6])
fig.update_yaxes(range=[-6,6])
```

**Here is a sample frame from the animation**
[image: Animation]

**To run the animation, you can either drag the slider bar or click the Play button**